# View lines above and below current cursor

Tags: scrolling

Is there a way to get 10 lines above and beneath the current cursor?

Similar to `set scrolloff=10` but I only want to do it ONCE, not change the setting...

*Clarification*: I want *at least* 10 lines. If there's already 10+ lines above and below the cursor then the command shouldn't change anything. `zz` and `z.` are close but they do a little too much.

Sorry for the exacting request, I'm not sure there's an easy way to do this

Comment: Does `z.` do what you want?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Or [`zz`](https://vimhelp.org/scroll.txt.html#zz) which is the same but leaves the cursor in the same column...

Comment: Hi @NDavis and welcome to [vi.se]! You might want to be more specific about what exactly you're after. Do you want *at least* 10 lines above and below the current cursor (since the screen might have more than 21 lines total)? Is putting the current line as the middle line a good enough solution? (See comments above.) Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! `z.` and `zz` are close to what I need but if the cursor is already close to center then I don't want to move it. Sorry to be choosy! @ChristianBrabandt @filbranden

Comment: @NDavis not possible as far as I know with built-in functions. Either do not press `z.`/`zz` in that case, after all you would only press it, if you want it to move the cursor, right? Or set the option value, or write a function that you bind to a key that takes care of that edge case.

Comment: @filbranden ah yes, I remember. I tend to ignore that command, because it is so close to `ZZ`

Comment: It can be done with a mapping and a function... If I have some time tomorrow I'll see if I can write something that does that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brute force way to do it:

```
:let scrolloff_before = &scrolloff | set scrolloff=10 | redraw | let &scrolloff = scrolloff_before | unlet scrolloff_before
```

This works by [saving the current `'scrolloff'` value in a variable](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Alet-option), setting it to `10`, [redrawing the screen](https://vimhelp.org/various.txt.html#%3Aredraw) so the update is applied (which is necessary because we are running all the commands in a single command-line), and then resetting `'scrolloff'` to the original value. Finally, we [remove the variable](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#%3Aunlet), which isn't really necessary but it's nice to be tidy.

Obviously you don't want to type that in every time, so you can make a command by adding the following to your `.vimrc`:

```
command ScrollOff10 let s:scrolloff_before = &scrolloff | set scrolloff=10 | redraw | let &scrolloff = s:scrolloff_before
```

As we're now in a script, we can use [script-local variables](https://vimhelp.org/eval.txt.html#script-variable) to decrease the chances of our variable overwriting a pre-existing one (and we don't bother to `unlet` it, as it's not visible outside the script.

Or a mapping:

```
nnoremap <F1> :let s:scrolloff_before = &scrolloff<CR>:set scrolloff=10<CR>:let &scrolloff = s:scrolloff_before<CR>
```

This version doesn't need the `:redraw` either, because instead of concatenating the commands with [`:bar`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#%3Abar), we're entering them one at a time with (mapped) presses of the <kbd>Return</kbd> key.

Answer (score 2):

This is essentially packing [@Rich's solution](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/25201/18609) (temporarily setting `'scrolloff'`) into a function, to improve readability.

I'm also defining a command and a mapping with a little bit more of flexibility (allowing a custom offset to be specified through a "count") and usability.

```
function! ScrollOffset(offset)
    let save_scrolloff = &l:scrolloff
    let &l:scrolloff = a:offset ? a:offset : 10
    redraw
    let &l:scrolloff = save_scrolloff
endfunction

command! -bar -count=0 ScrollOffset call ScrollOffset(<count>)

nnoremap <silent> z. :<C-u>call ScrollOffset(v:count)<CR>
```

You can employ it by using one of the following commands:

- `z.` to scroll with a default of 10
- `:ScrollOffset` does the same.
- `5z.` to scroll with a custom offset of 5 (specified as a "count" to the command)
- `:ScrollOffset 5` does the same.
- `:5ScrollOffset` also does the same.

Comment: thanks for putting it in the function :)